# how do I append a line to a .py file through python code itself?

Tags: python, file

How do I add Python code to a script, through Python code?

Comment: There's no difference to writing to a text file.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Python files generally *are* text files. Did you encounter any problems when just writing to the .py files?

Comment: i have tried with normal open and write commands and nothing happened

Comment: If you have encountered a problem with the obvious approach, please [edit] your question to add a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

The file you are trying to append to being a .py will not make a difference.

Just simply open it in append mode ("a" instead of "w"), and write away:

file1 = open("myfile.py", "a")